# “terrorist” vs. “freedom fighter” – what's a more neutral word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Yes, often history ends up being pretty clear on which was which.  This isn't meant to introduce moral equivalence when there isn't any.  But sometimes the situation is more ambiguous, such as liberation wars fought without respect for the laws of war.

So, what word to use when you want to remain strictly neutral, for example, when trying to communicate with people on both sides of the conflict?

“Rebel” sounds good, except that, at least in modern times, I at least perceive somewhat of a (positive) connotation of rebellion against oppressive central governments.

Comment: The Merriam-Webster definition of *rebel* is neutral. I also don't ascribe anything positive or negative to it. How are we to determine a neutral word when there is nothing objective to say that *rebel* isn't? In other words, can you point to something that says *rebel* is positive that would allow us to rule out other such words? Otherwise: insurgent, insurrectionary, insurrectionist, mutineer, red, revolter, revolutionary, revolutionist, challenger, defier, insubordinate, oppositionist, resister, anarchist, discontent, extremist, malcontent, radical.

Comment: Are you looking for a euphemism that won't offend anyone?  In the situation you describe, there is no neutral word.  What sounds neutral to you as a disinterested party would be highly offensive to partisans of one or both sides.  Even "fighters" would likely be found objectionable (too honorable to apply to terrorists' cowardly acts and too neutral a word to apply to freedom fighters with a holy cause).

Comment: @fixer1234 Of course there are neutral words. Calling ISIS fighters "fighters" isn't honouring or legitimising them in any way, it's just a statement that their members are fighting for whatever twisted cause they believe in. You would have to pretty damn suspicious to read anything into "ISIS fighters" other than that they are fighting for their cause, eg. any sympathy for them or seeing them as courageous. Also the members of the Wehrmacht fought for their leaders as soldiers, seamen, pilots etc. I don't see how anyone could take this statement as offensive or as an endorsement of Nazis.

Comment: @Zebrafish, I wasn't referring to disinterested 3rd parties, rather the partisans, themselves.  Each side sees the other side in extreme terms and their own side as righteous.  Neither side would see a neutral term as acceptable for themselves or their enemy.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm not understanding. Leaving aside "disinterested 3rd parties", consider a "partisan" who is on one side of a conflict. Any soldier on one side would would use the term soldier or fighter to describe the opposing side's troops. The opposing side is the enemy but the words "soldier" and "fighter" themselves are not loaded terms. The American soldier invading Iraq sees himself as a soldier and the those in the Iraqi army as soldiers. Both see themselves as fighters for their own country, and both see the other soldier as a fighter for theirs.

Comment: @Zebrafish, I was drawing a distinction between soldiers and "holy warriors".  Soldiers do a job for a government.  They may or may not be gung-ho for the cause; they're there doing a job.  With terrorists and "holy wars", the fighters are personally committed to a higher cause, and view things in extreme terms.  The people subject to terrorist attacks don't see the terrorists as fighters or soldiers, they see them as insane cowardly animals, carrying out atrocities on defenseless civilians, and not conforming to the rules of war.  (cont'd)

Comment: The terrorists view their enemy as less than human.  My point wasn't really specific to "fighters", but about the parties engaged in a conflict involving terrorism.  Third parties can use terms that seem neutral to other third parties.  But the participants in the conflict view things in such extreme terms that they see "neutral" words as a disservice to both sides of the conflict.

Comment: @Zebrafish ~ "soldier" and "fighter" are both loaded terms. One is a representative of a state with connotations of legitimacy, the other does not represent any state and hence has connotations of illegitimacy.

Comment: re. neutrality or not.  Take a continuum stretching from WW2 French/Polish/Dutch Resistance fighters to ISIS today.  One is clearly a freedom fighter, given that they were fighting against Nazis.  Another is, equally clearly a terrorist.  No need for neutrality.  But there is a continuum of possible motives and deeds between the 2.  What happens when you hit the middle, where the deeds are neither wholly noble, nor wholly without justification?  If **you** feel there should be no call for neutrality, fine, but why should you project your values onto mine on a vocabulary question?

Comment: If you're referring to my comments, I suspect we're not talking about the same thing. What you describe in your comment, above, is different from what you describe in the question.  I'm in no way trying to project values or addressing a call for neutrality.  The question asks for words that the two sides of such a conflict would both view as neutral from their perspective.  My point was that in the kind of conflict you describe, the parties involved would tend not to see neutral words as applicable.  Such words would seem to elevate or legitimize the enemy and/or denigrate themselves.

Comment: @fixer1234   Pardon me in that case.  What I was looking for was a term that expressed my desire to avoid labelling the insurrectionists as good or evil.  How the audience would react is obviously out of my control.  For example, when this question receives `criminal` as a suggested word,  that's the very opposite of what I am looking for.  Maybe you didn't have that intent, but some of the other responses sure seem to.

Comment: The term **combatants** is neutral (refers just to the fact that they are in a fighting role).  However, that actually has a legal definition what would preclude its use here.  It's limited by international agreement to soldiers fighting under the flag of a recognized government.  The point of the definition is to distinguish fighters who are "pawns" of their government from stateless actors operating outside any recognized authority, which would be the very people you're referring to.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher - is English your mother tongue?

Comment: @RoaringFish Though 'fighter' may well have the 'non-governmental' implications that you notice especially within the context where 'soldier' is also used, it certainly fits the OP's desire of a word with _less_ negative or positive feeling than 'rebel', 'terrorist', 'freedom fighter', 'insurgent', etc, etc. 'Fighter' may not be totally neutral but it is certainly more neutral than the others

Comment: @Dan.  depends... Not by birth, but been speaking English since I was 6, lived 40+ years in English countries.  700+ English SATs got me into, US, university ;-)  It's my most proficient language, by far.  I have a special interest in military history, including counterinsurgency warfare.  Tons of books read on subject.  Makes me, I believe, qualified to ask this question, though my question's phrasing of what I aimed for wrt neutrality might have been somewhat unclear.  See my answer to fixer1234 above.  Oh, and I really s*ck at formal grammar terminology, I learned by ear.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher - best (only?) way to learn I reckon; theory follows practice.  I only asked in case you had a word in your first language that you felt answered your question.

Comment: @Dan ah, seems like I had too thin a skin when responding.  My apologies.  No, in French, my first (my user handle is about gallows' humor rather than being Italian) language, we would have the same problem with terminology and it would also be difficult to tiptoe around finding a word that implies neither approval nor condemnation in this context.  And it would end much the same choices of words as those mentioned by others here ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "rebel" is either good or bad depending on who both you and the rebels are. The West might tend to view Syrian rebels fighting against the Assad regime as good because Assad is a dictator and supported by Russia. Houthi rebels in Yemen might be seen as bad because Saudi Arabia is officially an ally of the United States, and the belief that the rebels are supported by Iran.

The most neutral term I think is either "soldier", "forces", "troops" or simply "fighter".

Edit:

After considering disagreements from other users, I'd like to add their point that "soldier" and "troops" can often suggest members of a state/country's army, and that "fighter", quite distinctly from soldier, often suggests they are not soldiers of the state or country's army, thus delegitimising them and pejorating the word.

I agree with this, but I'd like to mention that all dictionaries I've checked define "soldier" as a member of an army, and that no dictionary I've seen necessarily requires an army to be state-controlled. Army often does refer to the military of a state, but doesn't have to.

When looking at the Wikipedia article on resistance movements I noticed an interesting line related to your question:

> In the media, an effort has been made by the BBC to avoid the phrases
>   "terrorist" or "freedom fighter", except in attributed quotes, in
>   favor of more neutral terms such as "militant", "guerrilla",
>   "assassin", "insurgent", "rebel", "paramilitary" or "militia".
>   [Resistance movement: Freedom fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_movement#Freedom_fighter)

I don't think many people would regard those alternatives as totally neutral, but apparently the BBC considers them "more" neutral than terrorist or freedom fighter. More specifically "terrorist" and "freedom fighter" can be seen as terms of approval or condemnation by a writer. The other words are less likely to be seen as such, and more likely to be seen as mere descriptions of the fighters.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81947/discussion-on-answer-by-zebrafish-terrorist-vs-freedom-fighter--whats-a-m).

Comment: Accepted.  The BBC has a point, and `fighter`, `guerrilla`, `insurgent` are also all fairly neutral terms that convey the context without elaborating on the speaker's sympathies.  `Soldier` I definitely disagree with as it has often caused controversies when claimed by insurgents.

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks "...what word to use when you want to remain strictly neutral?"

Sometimes, even with the best will in the world, neutrality is impossible.  And often commentators reveal/betray their bias (more or less intentionally) by the way they conjugate descriptors "irregularly":

> I'm a freedom fighter, you're a soldier, s/he's is a terrorist;
>
> I'm religious, you're devout, s/he's a fundamentalist;
>
> I know what I like, you're quite picky, s/he's fussy;
>
> I'm an artist, you're very expressive, s/he's whacko;
>
> I live within my means, you're careful with money, s/he's a mean skinflint;
>
> *etc*...

Comment: I agree with you that neutrality is impossible, but I thought the OP was trying to avoid labelling someone as terrorist or freedom fighter?

Comment: @RoaringFish - OP looking for more 'neutral' word than either...

Answer (score -4):

I would go with "criminal".

There are a lot of problems with defining 'terrorism', many of which hinge on the parties doing the defining not separating acts of terrorism from the ideology behind it, so they get tangled up trying to find a definition that doesn't include guerrilla warfare, or fighting for independence, etc - plus all the mess of taking political advantage by labelling X as a terrorist, while avoiding labelling themselves as a terrorist.

Alex Schmidd sidestepped all this quite neatly by offering a suggestion that terrorism is a [war-crime committed by civilians](https://scholarlycommons.law.case.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1228&context=faculty_publications). On that basis, "criminal" should cover it if you want to avoid the terrorist-freedom fighter trap.